# Executing stored Procedure on Oracle Database from SSIS

Tags: oracle, ssis, execute

I have a SP which is Merge type in nature. For the purpose, I am laoding a temp table with data on Oracle database and Then I am inserting/Updating my destination table by calling this stored procedure. I am not passing any parameter inside this stored procedure.

When I used {call mystoredprocedure ()} using ado net or old db connection for oracle database, the execute sql task just goes yellow and never finishes up.

I have called this stored procedure directly on sql developer and it work fine.

Can anyone suggest me to do this correctly.

Comment: What component has the stored procedure call?

Comment: SQL Execute task. However, I was able to solve this. I just had to define datatype within SP on oracle database even though I am not passing from outside.

Answer (score 0):

In Toad or SQL Developer, I would call my Oracle procedure with:

```
EXEC SCHEMA.MY_PROCEDURE();
```

In SSIS, in a SQL task, I can call my Oracle procedure like:

```
BEGIN SCHEMA.MY_PROCEDURE(); 
END;
```